# Should I neglect Java Script while load testing my website?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, load-testing, stress-testing

We're developing a web application which must tolerate noticeable amount of load. I'm running my tests on a HP (Proliant DL 380) server (two 3.6GHz Xeon cpus, 16 GBs of RAM, ...). I'm using Apache JMeter and pylot to run load tests (they kinda show similar results).

In one scenario, I configured the load testing program to hit my index page ,using just one thread, as much as it can. The index page is about 60KB and consists of about 10 ajax calls, lots of JavaScript and jQuery Codes, required CSS and etc.
The results I got was, well, disappointing.

Full index.jsp page:

- Throughput (req/sec): 3.567
- Response Time (secs): 0.278

So I removed every ajax call, got rid of charts and also CSS (but not JS)

- Throughput (req/sec): 6.082
- Response Time (secs): 0.161

Still very low! So I built an static index page in HTML format which contains all the data with the same size (without any server side and client side computation)

- Throughput (req/sec): 20.787
- Response Time (secs): 0.046

Wow, that was a breakthrough! Now I added some of the JavaScript codes to the index.html page

- Throughput (req/sec): 9.617
- Response Time (secs): 0.103

Well, I think the bottleneck has been found, Java Script codes. I need to find out how many req/sec "the server" can handle and since java Script is run client side, I don't think I should include it in this test. So should load testing tools process JS codes? (they seem to be doing this)

Another key question is, according to hardware, content size and aforementioned configs, is this amount of throughput plausible? shouldn't I expect more? my expectation is 500 req/sec! is the only solution adding hardware?!

BTW, the webapp has been built using Java+Struts2+JSP+Hibernate+MySQL. it is also distributed over multiple servers using haproxy. but the aforementioned tests was run on a single server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your JavaScript (CSS,images) directly embedded on the page or loaded from a script tag? The latter case will force the browser to download the file from the server ,instantly halving your paged per second.that's one of the reasons you should load jquery from a different server ( eg Google) - this will have a minor hit on the user perceived page load time (one additional DNS query to be made) but really takes the load off your server

Comment: Great point! well, some of them are embedded in the page and some of them loaded from a script tag. But in the test above I inserted some custom JS codes inside the page, and it halved my req/sec.

Comment: I do not see how executing javascript can slow down your pages - javascript, when downloaded embedded in the page, is just text - execution is performed by the client and should not affect the server at all. What I think is happening is that the machine(s) you use as clients are not powerful enough to run more than 9.617 javascript per second, and that's the bottleneck during your tests.

Comment: Actually your comment was the answer to my dilemma, The machine I was testing from wasn't powerful enough to send huge requests!

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is a raw number of how fast the server can serve up the content, then I would say yes, ignore the java-script and focus on how fast it takes to transfer all the various bits of the page (HTML, images, script files, CSS, etc).

However, if you are trying to test user experience, well JS is part of that, so you need to take that into account.  From your description, you are not worried about user experience but rather load to the server.

You might want to consider setting up JMeter to make direct calls to the pieces of your pages, as described in the first sentence above.

Comment: I'm with you about JS, but I don't think configuring JMeter to make direct calls to page is a good idea. Because there are also ajax calls, db accesses, etc to take into account. One of the major bottlenecks is the application server's cpu which in this scenario will be abandoned.

Comment: JMeter could be configured to make the same sort of ajax calls that the browser does.  My point was more or less that, if you wanted to negate JS as a factor, then you need to take it out of the equation.  The simplest way would be to just make whatever calls (normal HTTP, AJAX, WS) that the browser "would" make under normal circumstances.  The advantage of using JMeter is that you can easily ramp up the volume once you get the base tests done.  I by no means meant to suggest it was the only solution, as I am sure there are thousands of ways to accomplish the same feat.

Answer (score 1):

> Another key question is, according to hardware, content size and aforementioned configs, is this amount of throughput plausible? shouldn't I expect more? my expectation is 500 req/sec! is the only solution adding hardware?!

Writing your application so that pages are cacheable and then putting a http-proxy up in front of your application is often a good strategy.

Comment: Well I think HAProxy does this, and I have put a HA machine up in front of some Tomcat backends. But as I said, for simplicity I ran the test just on a single machine.

Comment: HAProxy doesn't cache, it's a load balancer. You typically put a cache, such as Varnish, Squid or nginx in front of HAProxy. But your application still needs to allow the cache to work, by separating cacheable from non-cacheable (private) content and issuing proper http headers to communicate this to the cache.